# Union type of an interface field is not considered, when typechecking a call by overloaded function

Tags: typescript

I have an existing interface `ICon` with overloaded functions. It has a sink function for weakly typed calls.

Problem is that when I create a union type of all possible overloads it's not considered unless I use a type on first level. It produces compiling error `Object is possibly 'undefined'.`

What can I do to have a union type as an interface field and still have correct strong typing?

[playground link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play/index.html?ssl=29&ssc=48&pln=29&pc=47#code/JYOwLgpgTgZghgYwgAgJIGED2JkG8CwAUMicgOYRhbhSYA2AFAtmLXQHJwC2EAXMgCI4AgJT8Azq1BkA3EVLlK1VvSYs2nHvwEAjURKkhZ80hSrrVzGvU19kkqNLHIAriAAmEGKAju5hAF8iIgB6EOQAYmQARmQAWjjkbyhJZDoIADcIOjTMBDgct2BsZDAATwAHCGDCcqrc-LoAVRBikAAVSpQAXkFhZAAfQT1-InSwZDh+OjyClrbO+t6hAVHCceQuPIBramRe3EVzazp+BgAPA0cjEX2APmRzgMnxNGo1sOTU9KycupRgK84CACmUAF6+ZDMKBQCAIMB0MpELYIXbYAB0ZmUbAYcBE6LAmAAMrN0k0KlUoOg4OIIAwRGtQuEogAmeKJIolf7IUCTHCgSCwRDVQhEAXQeBINAANQKeBMJAyBW0-SGugERCCovWlEmOn4qFlOQOCuQStOfQ1gQ+4XYAHl2gBRfgAAzgLr57mQbp06PNHrgsOQmBgpQAFihxNwUP8AIREKziegQdEzMgMf4hyb7bq9TOhuC+80MmphSLIO06ABWcImgOQFUw4nEwB0iOQAHI3J5vCBfB30UzQJ5YfDSl1kO5MBBXiBMBNaTGw3A62AO69gFxG83W+lSphkDoUN2vD53IOdRN4VBjZsdtRMUoLIxC36CiIE6w6ATiaSIOTKWpWl6UZQgyyiABmdkoUwLgdFAFc2hqcUhSlQ05QIYhSHNaZSXmbBFhFLUxl1QtogNI19nlLDFWVS1NRtctKxrMd623Fs2zKTsT17fsLzCYdoFrcd6inGdkDnBcICXFceTXDctybDi90JQ9jw8U8+3PEiry-WJehRNEQEfY4VBfIt30-G9oh-ElGn-CloCAukS0IIA)

```
interface ICon {
    getControl(controlName: "a"): string;
    getControl(controlName: "b"): string;
    getControl(controlName: string): undefined;
}

// # 1 -- first level local union type

type localUnionType = "a" | "b";

let a: localUnionType = "a";

let mockCon = {} as ICon;

//first level type is analyzed correctly
mockCon.getControl(a).toLocaleUpperCase();


// # 2 -- union type in an interface

interface IVal {
    val: "a" | "b"
}

let ab: IVal = {
    val: "a"
};

// # Object is possibly 'undefined'.
//inderect type does not see that it's impossible to be undefined.
let ctrl = mockCon.getControl(ab.val)
ctrl.toLocaleUpperCase();


// # 3 -- combination

interface IVal {
    val: localUnionType
}

let ab1: IVal = {
    val: "a"
};

// # Object is possibly 'undefined'.
//inderect type does not see that it's impossible to be undefined.
let ctrl1 = mockCon.getControl(ab.val)
ctrl1.toLocaleUpperCase();
```

Answer (score 0):

For an union type value use an overloaded function that accept an union type:

```
interface ICon {
    getControl(controlName: "a" | "b"): string;
    getControl(controlName: string): undefined;
}
```

With the signature:

```
getControl(controlName: "a"): string;
```

`controlName` can be a value of the literal type `"a"`.

But `"a" | "b"` can not be used when an `"a"` is expected: in other words `"a" | "b"` is not a subtype of `"a"`.

Typescript will always fallback to:

```
getControl(controlName: string): undefined;
```

Comment: thank you for the answer! I was hoping my interface and interface with explicit union type are the same thing...

Comment: But! In my code you can see that it accepts union type -- type `localUnionType`. I don't see whats different between it and same thing defined as interface field.

Comment: `getControl` accepts `ab.val` because its type is `"a" | "b"` that is 
a subtype of `string`. This implies that the overloaded function that match is
`getControl(controlName: string): undefined`: this gives you the error 
`Object is possibly undefined` when calling `ctrl.toLocaleUpperCase()`.
Hope that this help.

Comment: `a` and `ab.val` are of the same type: typeof a === typeof ab.val, but only ab.val produces this error.

Comment: But also `typeof a === typeof "another string"`. You are confusing `typeof` TypeScript keyword used as a type query with the [typeof](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/typeof) javascript operator.